# Функция load не грузит js-код

Tags: jquery, javascript

Таким образом загружается только html-код части страницы

```
$(".wrepper_reviews").load("{$home}/product/{$row.name_translite}_{$row.id}.html .wrepper_reviews");
```

Как "заставить" загружать и js-код?

Answer (score 1):

Для подгрузки скриптов, существует или сокращенная форма ajax-запроса [$.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/), или пользоваться полной, указав **dataType:"script"**.